¿Como mostrar un Comparativo de las Ventas por MESES, AÑOS de un Almacén especifico en una Sola Fila de la CONSULTA?
Esta es la consulta que tengo de momento:
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT( 
      CONCAT(
      'IF(MONTH(r.FECHA) = ''',
      IDMES,
      ''', TOTALVENTA, 0) AS ',
      NOMBREMES
    ))
FROM meses
where IDMES BETWEEN MONTH('2024-01-01') AND MONTH('2024-02-29') into @sql;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT MONTH(r.FECHA) AS IDMES, alm.NOMALMACEN AS ALMACEN,', @sql,'
                  FROM registrodiario AS r
                  INNER JOIN almacen AS alm
                  ON alm.CODALMACEN = r.ALMACENID
                  WHERE ALMACENID = 1 GROUP BY MONTH(r.FECHA), YEAR(r.FECHA), ALMACEN

                  ');

PREPARE consulta FROM @sql;
EXECUTE consulta;

Este el Resultado:

El Resultado que quiero es este:

Agradesco su ayuda en esto de antemano

Por favor, no uses imágenes para mostrar tus datos. Estos no son accesibles para todos, y lo hacen más difícil para nosotros construir datos para probar consultas.

Lo que buscas se llama agregación condicional y tiene un CASE WHEN en la funciona de agregación.
SELECT 
  alm.nomalmacen AS almacen,
  SUM(CASE WHEN r.fecha >= DATE '2023-01-01' AND r.fecha < DATE '2023-01-02' THEN r.totalventa END) AS enero_2023,
  SUM(CASE WHEN r.fecha >= DATE '2023-01-02' AND r.fecha < DATE '2023-01-03' THEN r.totalventa END) AS febrero_2023,
  SUM(CASE WHEN r.fecha >= DATE '2024-01-01' AND r.fecha < DATE '2024-01-02' THEN r.totalventa END) AS enero_2024,
  SUM(CASE WHEN r.fecha >= DATE '2024-01-02' AND r.fecha < DATE '2024-01-03' THEN r.totalventa END) AS febrero_2024
FROM almacen AS alm
LEFT JOIN registrodiario AS r ON r.almacenid = alm.codalmacen
GROUP BY almacen
ORDER BY almacen;

Si quieres cero en vez de NULL en los resultados, usa COALESCE:
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN ... END), 0) AS ...


Tu respuesta esta genial, pero veo que una consulta estática, tal vez creando una variable para el año y que esta sea igual al rango de fecha que seleccione...

Si, claro, puedes hacerlo. O, si los rangos dependen de la fecha actual, puedes calcularlos.

No logro conseguir el resultado, si alguien más tiene una forma, agradezco

Mi consulta funciona para esos cuatro meses, ¿si? Pero quieres una consulta que funciona con otros meses también. Y por esos usas variables. Algo como SUM(CASE WHEN r.fecha >= @fecha1 AND r.fecha < @fecha2 THEN .... ¿Qué es que no funciona? Quizás sería buena idea aceptar esta respuesta y hacer una nueva pregunta separada con el problema nuevo. Explícanos en esta que has tratado y que problemas surgieron.
